# Are these Spanish American War uniforms?

Tags: united-states, war, uniform, cuba

Can anyone identify the uniforms these men are wearing?  The young man in this picture may be my Grandfather, who fought in the Spanish American War.  He was underage when he joined to fight.
[image]

Comment: If the picture is of your grandfather, what regiment would this be? I ask because many of the regiments, particularly of volunteers, had non-standard uniforms.

Comment: [This image](http://www.tn4me.org/pics/fulls/2soldiersblurry.jpg) shows that the absence of breast pockets did occur at the time, though it was unusual. [Here](http://www.spanamwar.com/Americanuniforms.htm) are some references that might help out.